# Monitor IIS 6.0

Tags: performance, iis, iis-6, monitoring

What good tools can I use to monitor IIS. What is included seems to be not as useful as I'd like. I realize I can add performance counters; those don't tell me very much; it's just a collections of properties that are plugged into a generic graphing tool.

I have problems with old legacy applications hanging and various and sundry other things. Also, when I need to get basic information like how many connections I have in IIS and their **details** I don't know what to do. I've googled extensively and I cannot find much. I find some log parsers, but I want real time. I found some commerical tools that don't really seem quite what I want, besides I'd like to find something free. This is very basic stuff that is pretty easy to get in Apache. I found [IISTracer](http://iismonitor.motobit.com/) but I am a bit skeptical of it; I did install and try it out. Is there anything else? Some of these legacy applications are classic ASP so just a CLR Profiler isn't what I'm looking for, although those are handy.

EDIT: Is IISTracer really the only tool like this out there for IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tools for Troubleshooting IIS 6.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780913.aspx)

[IIS Request Monitor (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f0831c18-39e1-4d13-99e7-8a32362ba4ff.mspx?mfr=true)

One of the techniques for tracking down and mitigating problems with badly behaving sites is to use [Application Pools](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true). This [article](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511) shows how to set one up.

It has also been mentioned here on SO:

- [What causes an application pool in IIS to recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle)
- [Pros and cons of having dedicated application pools over keeping web applications in one default app pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223326/pros-and-cons-of-having-dedicated-application-pools-over-keeping-web-applications)

Comment: Yeah, that Request Monitor was the only thing that looked remotely promising on the first link. I'll google for awhile and see if I can find it or how to run it (no info on either page). But it's command line so I'm a little skeptical given how MS command line tools work. Thanks though.

Comment: I really think there should be more tools than this. However, I did solve my problem using Process Monitor. This helped me find a problem with the .NET SMTP API that was causing issues. So, Ill just accept this answer.